# How to fadIn with ajax request?

Tags: ajax

I've this code, i'd like to replace the 'ul.hello-list' content with the answer datas. I'm trying

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "home/hello.php",
        data: {
            "action": "hello_action"
        },
        success: function(datas) {
            if (datas) {
                $("ul.hello-list").fadeOut(); 
                // It doesn't work
                datas.fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thxs

Comment: What is datas?  At the very least you need to wrap it in a $() function.

Comment: datas = "<ul><li> Hello world </li><li> How are you ?</li></ul>";

Answer (score 0):

So from your comment, I believe you can do:

```
success: function(datas) {
    if (datas) {
        var $newContent = $(datas).hide();
        var $oldList = $("ul.hello-list");
        var $container = $oldList.parent(); // Replace this with whatever your container is

        $oldList.fadeOut();
        $newContent.appendTo($container).fadeIn();
    }
}
```

The issue is that `datas` is not inherently a jQuery object, so you cannot call jQuery functions on it.  Furthermore, it needs to be attached to the DOM before it can be faded in.